# Bluetooth Scans Devices, But Cannot Write to Device After Frequent Scanning

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

**Use Case:** I wrote a security app, which runs alongside a bluetooth Mesh. The mesh contains custom lights and alarms. To check the status of the mesh system, my app scans one of the nearest devices (by RSSI strength) to see what data the bluetooth light/alarm contains in it's scan response packet. Because this is a security app, **my app scans every 15 seconds** to ensure it has the latest info at all times. Security threats are reported to the police, so it is important to be as up to date as possible. Seconds matter. After a couple of weeks or so of the app running, the app is able to scan the data, but can no longer connect to a device. The only way to "clear" an alarm is by using the app, so it is necessary to be able to write to a device when needed.

**My Question:** Why does this happen? How is it possible that I can scan devices, but no longer write to a device?

**Affected Device Logcat:** I was able to locate a device that was in this problem-state and collected the logcat while trying to write to a device. As you can see, I am able to connect, see the services, and even update the MTU. But cannot write to the device. My app automatically tries 5 attempts, and this is the last attempt. Please note that I tried toggling bluetooth on and off. Restarting the tablet did seem to fix the issue. Unfortunately, I didn't try closing and restarting the app first....

```
E/Bluetooth LE: Best RSSI Position set
E/Bluetooth LE: Bluetooth Device saved                      
D/BluetoothGatt: connect() - device: 00:A0:50:E1:88:51, auto: false
D/BluetoothGatt: registerApp()
D/BluetoothGatt: registerApp() - UUID=3b720df8-2e40-47bf-aa2c-99c0c1fba362
E/Bluetooth LE: Attempting To Connect to GATT
D/BluetoothGatt: onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=6
D/BluetoothGatt: onClientConnectionState() - status=0 clientIf=6 device=00:A0:50:E1:88:51
D/BluetoothGatt: discoverServices() - device: 00:A0:50:E1:88:51
D/BluetoothGatt: onConnectionUpdated() - Device=00:A0:50:E1:88:51 interval=6 latency=0 timeout=500 status=0
D/BluetoothGatt: onSearchComplete() = Device=00:A0:50:E1:88:51 Status=0
E/Bluetooth: GATT Services count: 3
E/Bluetooth: Service Found - UUID: 00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
E/Bluetooth: Service Found - UUID: 00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
E/Bluetooth: Service Found - UUID: 0000cbbb-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
D/BluetoothGatt: configureMTU() - device: 00:A0:50:E1:88:51 mtu: 50
D/BluetoothGatt: onConnectionUpdated() - Device=00:A0:50:E1:88:51 interval=39 latency=0 timeout=500 status=0
D/BluetoothGatt: onConfigureMTU() - Device=00:A0:50:E1:88:51 mtu=50 status=0
D/Surface: Surface::disconnect(this=0x74241f7000,api=1)
D/View: [Warning] assignParent to null: this = android.widget.LinearLayout{f04b3f V.E...... ......ID 0,0-333,75}
D/BluetoothManager: getConnectedDevices
D/BluetoothManager: getConnectedDevices
E/Bluetooth Gatt: Closing Gatt
D/BluetoothGatt: cancelOpen() - device: 00:A0:50:E1:88:51
D/BluetoothGatt: close()
D/BluetoothGatt: unregisterApp() - mClientIf=6
D/BluetoothManager: getConnectedDevices
W/package.name: type=1400 audit(0.0:38806): avc: denied { search } for name="custom" dev="dm-0" ino=3890 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c100,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:custom_file:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
D/ViewRootImpl[Toast]: hardware acceleration = true , fakeHwAccelerated = false, sRendererDisabled = false, forceHwAccelerated = false, sSystemRendererDisabled = false
D/Surface: Surface::connect(this=0x74241f7000,api=1)
D/Surface: Surface::allocateBuffers(this=0x74241f7000)
D/BluetoothAdapter: isLeEnabled(): ON
D/BluetoothLeScanner: onScannerRegistered() - status=6 scannerId=-1 mScannerId=0
D/BluetoothAdapter: isLeEnabled(): ON
D/BluetoothLeScanner: could not find callback wrapper
```

**Further Testing:** To conduct some testing, I made a small app that can toggle a light on and off. I set the app to scan every 3 seconds for over an hour. The results were similar in that I could scan for devices, but not connect and toggle the light by writing data to it. After the issue occured in the new toggle-app, I swapped over to my main security app, which had been running the whole time, and it worked fine. Apparently, the issue only affects the app that is scanning too frequently. The difference in the logcat bothers me a bit though - after the problem occurred, the logcat shows the onClientRegistered status as 133, which makes some sense. The main app did not show that though. I wonder if these are two different issues?

```
D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
D/BluetoothLeScanner: Start Scan with callback
D/BluetoothLeScanner: onScannerRegistered() - status=0 scannerId=9 mScannerId=0
D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=88
D/ViewRootImpl@dc2b515[Toast]: setView = android.widget.LinearLayout{251b02a V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0} TM=true MM=false
V/Toast: Text: Uogg in android.widget.Toast$TN@af0fe1b
D/ViewRootImpl@dc2b515[Toast]: dispatchAttachedToWindow
D/ViewRootImpl@dc2b515[Toast]: Relayout returned: old=[0,63][1080,2094] new=[247,1810][832,1926] result=0x7 surface={valid=true 509882912768} changed=true
D/OpenGLRenderer: eglCreateWindowSurface = 0x76b4a19080, 0x76b763d010
D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
D/BluetoothGatt: connect() - device: 00:A0:50:DF:22:58, auto: false
D/BluetoothAdapter: isSecureModeEnabled
D/BluetoothGatt: registerApp()
D/BluetoothGatt: registerApp() - UUID=0241923a-48e6-426a-81c0-acbea6690766
D/BluetoothGatt: onClientRegistered() - status=133 clientIf=0
E/BluetoothÂ LE: Disconnected from GATT
E/BluetoothÂ Gatt: Closing Gatt
D/BluetoothGatt: cancelOpen() - device: 00:A0:50:DF:22:58
D/BluetoothGatt: close()
D/BluetoothGatt: unregisterApp() - mClientIf=0
```

**Airplane Mode:** For some reason, toggling bluetooth on and off did nothing, but turning on Airplane mode solved the onClientRegistered() - status 133 issue. I have no idea why this would be. Does Airplane mode clear all bluetooth cache or similar? Currently, my attempt was to toggle bluetooth off/on every 6 hours, but that doesn't seem to work. I'm not clearing the cache though.

Other than having the clients turn their devices off nightly, which I can't guarantee they do, nothing seems to resolve the issue. Any thoughts are welcome here.

**Edit:** I turned off my device's bluetooth and noticed that my logcat shows `D/BluetoothAdapter: isLeEnabled(): ON` when trying to toggle one of the Bluetooth lights. I also saw this appear in my affected device's logcat after trying to scan and connect to a device. I'm wondering if I need to toggle bluetooth and Bluetooth LE both off to refresh everything. Toggling bluetooth on and off does nothing helpful at this point. I am using a BluetoothLE scanner, so it would make some sense. A little odd toggling bluetooth doesn't affect LE. Searching google shows the below ([Full Code/Credit Here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.java)):

```
@SystemApi
public boolean isLeEnabled() {
    final int state = getLeState();
    if (DBG) {
        Log.d(TAG, "isLeEnabled(): " + BluetoothAdapter.nameForState(state));
    }
    return (state == BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON
            || state == BluetoothAdapter.STATE_BLE_ON
            || state == BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_ON
            || state == BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_OFF);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use this code:

```
Future<void> scanPrinters() async {
// CHECK TO PUT INIT
flutterBlue.startScan(timeout: Duration(seconds: 4));
flutterBlue.scanResults.listen((results) {
  for (blueB.ScanResult r in results) {
    print('Device ${r.device.name} found!');
  }
});

printerManager.startScan(Duration(seconds: 3));    
printerManager.scanResults.listen((results) {
  print("dipositi" + results.toString());
  setState(() {
    printers = results;
  });
});
}
```

Comment: This code is just how to run a scan in flutter... I obviously know how to run scans lol. The question is why, after scanning in my app, I am being blocked from writing to a device. It seems like some type of security measure. I'm actually using java, but it's nice to see some flutter - which I'm working on learning. Nonetheless - thank you for your response.